# How can I use Websockets to send data from a Google Cloud Function to Next.js?

Tags: next.js, websocket, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a Next.js application where a user submits many URLs to be scraped. I render a table of the submitted URLs to the user and then send batches of 5 URLs to Google Cloud Functions to be scraped via Google Cloud Tasks. After the URLs are scraped, I'd like to send the scraped data back to the Next.js client via Websockets and render those updates to the table. I have never used WebSockets before and I want to understand how to do this. How can I send messages from the Google Cloud Function and receive them in my Next.js client application?

Comment: You will need to use a different product for this. Cloud Run is the closest match. Either that, or use another channel of communication, such as one of the Firebase databases.